# Trying to use a count column in the where part of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

There is 2 tables called

**Students**

- stuID
- camID FK

**Campus**

- camID PK
- camName

I am trying to find the campuses with more than 4 students that include the camName, camID,  (number of students)

This is what I got so far

```
SELECT 
    students.camID, campus.camName, SUM(students.stuID) as [count] 
FROM 
    students 
JOIN 
    campus ON campus.camID = students.camID 
WHERE 
    [count] > 3 
GROUP BY 
    students.camID, campus.camName
ORDER BY 
    [count]
```

All this gets me though is a error that 'Invalid comlumn name 'count'.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the `WHERE` clause is evaluated *before* the alias is even created.  You also can't use an alias in the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT students.camID, campus.camName, COUNT(students.stuID) as studentCount
FROM students
JOIN campus
    ON campus.camID = students.camID
GROUP BY students.camID, campus.camName
HAVING COUNT(students.stuID) > 3
ORDER BY studentCount
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be in a having clause, not a where clause?

Comment: @ZLK It helps to read the question.  Let's see whether this gets downvoted.

Comment: I mean it should be `GROUP BY students.camID, campus.camName HAVING SUM(students.stuID) > 3`, rather than an aggregate in a where clause.

Comment: YES! The second one works  but I have to use `SUM(students.stuID)` to prevent an invalid column name. Thanks a lot

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I get that the `WHERE` clause is (logically) evaluated before the `GROUP BY` but it seems to me that the `SELECT` and `HAVING` are evaluated within the same (logical) scope, so what's the (logical) reason for not allowing `studentCount` to be used in the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: @onedaywhen I don't know the answer to this, and the answer is RDMBS-specific.  I was curious myself, so I recently [asked this very question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187913/performance-implications-of-allowing-alias-to-be-used-in-having-clause).

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT [t0].* FROM campus AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t1].camID
    FROM students AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].camID ) 
    AS [t2] ON [t0].camID = [t2].camID
    WHERE [t2].[value] > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first SQL products didn't support derived tables, so `HAVING` was invented. But now we do have derived tables, so we no longer need `HAVING` and indeed it can cause confusion (note legacy functionality is never removed from the SQL Standard):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT students.camID, campus.camName,
               SUM(students.stuID) as [count]
          FROM students 
               JOIN campus ON campus.camID = students.camID 
         GROUP 
            BY students.camID, campus.camName
       ) AS DT1
 WHERE [count] > 3
 ORDER
    BY [count]
```