# Performance penalty for nested mysql queries

Tags: mysql, nested

What is the performance penalty for `SELECT * FROM Table` VS  `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table AS A) AS B`

My questions are: Firstly, does the SELECT * involve iteration over the rows in the table, or will it simply return all rows as a chunk without any iteration (because no WHERE clause was given), and if so does the nested query in example two involve iterating over the table twice, and will take 2x the time of the first query? thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question hinges on whether you are using mysql before 5.7, or 5.7 and after. I may be altering your question slightly, but hopefully the following captures what you are after.

Your `SELECT * FROM Table` does a table scan via the clustered index (the physical ordering). In the case of no primary key, one is [implicitly](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/) available to the engine. There is no where clause as you say. No filtering or choice of another index is attempted.

The [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) output (see [also](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)) shows 1 row in its summary. It is relatively straight forward. The explain output and performance with your derived table `B` will differ depending on whether you are on a version before  5.7, or 5.7 and after.

The document [Derived Tables in MySQL 5.7](http://mysqlserverteam.com/derived-tables-in-mysql-5-7/) describes it well for versions 5.6 and 5.7, where the latter will provide no penalty due to the change in materialized derived table output being incorporated into the outer query. In prior versions, substantial overhead was endured with temporary tables with the derived.

It is quite easy to test the performance penalty prior to 5.7. All it takes is a medium sized table to see the noticeable impact that your question's derived table has on impacting performance. The following example is on a small table in version 5.6:

```
explain 
select qm1.title  
from questions_mysql qm1 
join questions_mysql qm2 
on qm2.qid<qm1.qid 
where qm1.qid>3333 and qm1.status='O';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | qm1   | range | PRIMARY,cactus1 | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  5441 | Using where                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | qm2   | ALL   | PRIMARY,cactus1 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 10882 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3) |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------+


explain 
select b.title from 
(   select qid,title from questions_mysql where qid>3333 and status='O' 
) b 
join questions_mysql qm2 
on qm2.qid<b.qid; 
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | qm2             | index | PRIMARY,cactus1 | cactus1 | 10      | NULL | 10882 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ALL   | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  5441 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | questions_mysql | range | PRIMARY,cactus1 | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  5441 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Note, I did change the question, but it illustrates the impact that derived tables and their lack of index use with the optimizer has in versions prior to 5.7. The derived table benefits from indexes as it is being materialized. But thereafter it endures overhead as a temporary table and is incorporated into the outer query without index use. This is not the case in version 5.7

Comment: Great explanation :)

Comment: On the subject of performance, in a join operation between two subqueries, is it preferred to specify the LIMIT clause in an inner query rather than on the outer query? like: `((SELECT id FROM Table1 LIMIT 10) AS A NATURAL JOIN Table2))` would be better than `((SELECT id FROM Table1) AS A NATURAL JOIN Table2)) LIMIT 10`    (this might contain some syntax errors in relation to table-naming but...)? thanks :)

Comment: Best to play with it on your server version, your schema. The following is on [5.6](http://i.imgur.com/jxsrvB2.jpg), on a laptop non-server-grade. Note, I never use natural joins. I try not to make broad brush stroke answers. Especially just on `Explain` ouput that may seem identical. That happens too much on the stack. So instead, pointing our queries at larger datasets and perform at least 15 minutes of testing on our worst performing queries or general investigations like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38189113). The performance will vary by version based on the Optimizer.