# IN vs Regex mysql performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-workbench

Which query is more performant

```
User.joins('addresses').having("GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT addresses.status) REGEXP ?", '^approved$|^rejected$|^pending$')
```

OR

```
 User.joins('addresses').having("GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT addresses.status) in ('approved','rejected','pending')")
```

Comment: take a look at explain plan  ..

Comment: Can you write out the whole queries? Makes it easier to read and adds focus on the actual topic

Comment: Take a look at performance. Explain plan won't prove a ton. If you think that is not the case, look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38189113). Same explain plans different performances

Comment: By the way, the `in` clause can be a speed demon if setup properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/38002986